# Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type Map<String, String>

Tags: flutter, dart

Refer My code:In dart When I try to assign **value map** in the **params map cleintRequest**  I got this exception, Anybody please guide me

```
 const Map<String, int> value = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
  final Map<String, dynamic> params = {
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
```

Comment: Try write `<String, dynamic>{` (put "<String, dynamic>" before `{`)

Comment: code updated now

Comment: Also tried this but issue occurs                                                                              
    const Map<String, dynamic> tr = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
      final Map<String, dynamic> params = {
        "cname": channelName,
        "uid": userId,
        "clientRequest": tr
      };

Comment: Works fine in my case. Are you sure this is what is causing the error?

Comment: working fine in dartpad,but in flutter app I got the above exception

Comment: Is this your actual code?

Comment: might be related to this https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/351

Comment: Post your whole code

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are misunderstanding the type system in Dart. There are both type on variables but also type on the object itself you are creating.

In case of `Map` this can be a little confusing at first. E.g.:

```
  const Map<String, int> value = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
  print({
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  }.runtimeType); // _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>

  print(<String, dynamic>{
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  }.runtimeType); // _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
```

As you can see, the type of the Map can either be automatically determined or forced by specifying the type explicit.

In this case, Dart are trying to see what type there are in common with all the different types used as values. In this case this is `Object` since `String` and `Map<String, int>` does not have anything in common other than they are both objects.

Your problem is that the following code is not correct if you have [disabled implicit type casting](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks):

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> params = {
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
```

The map defined here will be determined to be `Map<String, Object>` but you are forcing it into a variable which can only point to a `Map<String, dynamic>` which gives your error.

A possible fix here is to tell the type you actually want when creating the map like:

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> params = <String, dynamic>{
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
```

Or simplify it with this since `tr` will automatically be determined to be a variable of the type `Map<String, dynamic>`:

```
  final params = <String, dynamic>{
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
```

And to fix your example:

```
void main() {
  const value = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
  final params = <String, dynamic>{
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
  print(params); // {cname: 45, uid: 33232, clientRequest: {resourceExpiredHour: 24}}
}
```

I should properly also add that the `dynamic` is really not needed for this specific example since we can also just do (since `Map<String, Object>` is a totally fine type for `params`):

```
void main() {
  const value = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
  final params = {
    "cname": '45',
    "uid": '33232',
    "clientRequest": value
  };
  print(params); // {cname: 45, uid: 33232, clientRequest: {resourceExpiredHour: 24}}
}
```

Comment: He is using Map<String, int> though and not Map<String, dynamic>

Comment: Yes, but in one of his comments he tried to use <String, dynamic>. But well, I have added an example of how to solve his first example.

Comment: Yeah great answer nonetheless

Comment: I am updating it now so it is actually based on the first example instead. Give me a minute or two :)

Comment: Using the fix  const value = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24}; the exception still occurs

Comment: const tr = {"resourceExpiredHour": 24};
      final params = <String, dynamic>{
        "cname": '45',
        "uid": '33232',
        "clientRequest": tr
      };

Comment: Unhandled Exception: InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type Map<String, String>

Comment: Like I said the code you posted is fine @Tester12. The issue is somewhere else

Comment: @Tester12 What line in that example are thowing that error? I am guessing your problem is you are giving your `Map` into some other method which are then thowing your error. So we need to see more of your code.

Comment: just clean and rebuild working fine, Thanks for support